# asmx webservice doesn't read postdata

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webforms, asmx

I have an .asmx webservice that works fine except it doesn't read prostdata. It looks like this:

```
namespace mynamespace.liby
{

    [ScriptService]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class json : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<sp_tech_keywordSearch_Result> search()
        {

            const string KEY = "key";
            var key = string.Empty;

            // convert postdata to dictionary
            // this piece of code works fine in my asp.net MVC controller but not here :-(
            string data = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            Dictionary<string, string> postData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);

            if (postData.ContainsKey(KEY)) { key = postData[KEY]; }

            var db = new my_Entities();
            var result = db.sp_myStoredProcedure(key);

            return result.ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the line

```
// if (postData.ContainsKey(KEY)) { key = postData[KEY]; }
```

the procedure is called without parameter and returns a list of values.
But when I keep this line it throws an error saying `postData` is null.
When i check it in debug mode I see that `data` is an empty string.

I call this service with angular like this:

```
callService: function () {
    var postData = new Object();
    postData.key =4;

    return $http({ method: 'POST', url: MY_SERVICE, data: postData })
        .then(function (obj) {
            _Result = obj.data.d;
            return true;
        }, function (err) {
            _Result = [];
            console.log('serviceError');
            return false;
        });
},
```

My guess is that my code for reading postdata is wrong somehow. I have the same code running in an ASP.NET MVC controller and it works fine there. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this solved the problem

```
// goto beginning of the inputstream
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

// convert postdata to dictionary
string data = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

For some reason the 'cursor' of the inputstream is on the last position and `ReadToEnd()` results in reading an empty string.